# starred chapter in header? (scrbook)

Tags: formatting, starred-version, scrbook

is there a possibility to show the unnumbered chapters (starred chapters) also in the headings of scrbook?

Here's a little code-example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,openright,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=35mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=15mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{mparhack}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thechapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{0pt}{}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{The concerning one ...}
\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[7]
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[8-10]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

The starred chapters should also appear in the headers like the non-starred do. (But, they shouldn't appear in the toc ...) - I hope this is somehow possible. (I also use the titlesec-package for formatting the chapters ... I hope this makes no 'additional difficulty' for my main problem ...).

Thank you in advance!
  eniem

EDIT: that's the chapter-/section-headers I use:

```
\newlength\widestnum
\setlength\widestnum{4em}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \colorbox{gray!20}{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
          \parbox[t]{\widestnum}{\thechapter}%
          \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\widestnum\relax}{#1}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \fbox{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
          \parbox[t]{\widestnum}{\thesection}%
          \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\widestnum\relax}{#1}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    %%\makebox[\linewidth]{%
    %%  \fbox{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
          \parbox[t]{\widestnum}{\thesubsection}%
          \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\widestnum\relax}{#1}%
        }%
    %%  }%
    %%}%
  }
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    %%\makebox[\linewidth]{%
    %%  \fbox{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
          \parbox[t]{\widestnum}{\thesubsubsection}%
          \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\widestnum\relax}{#1}%
        }%
    %%  }%
    %%}%
  }   
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[hang]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
%    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
 %     \colorbox{gray!20}{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{#1}%
  %    }%
  %  }%
  }
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \fbox{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \fbox{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
```

Comment: `\chapter[]{your chapter title}` if no entry should be made to the toc, so you don't need `\chapter*`

Comment: Perhaps define you header with `titleps`: titlesec gives you access to the `\chaptertitle` command. I guess you'd have to define the formatting of numbered *and*  unnumbered chapters with titlesec.

Comment: @eniem: It depends also, whether your un`toc`ed chapter should be numbered or not?

Comment: What about `\addchap*{}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no, it shouldn't be numbered ...

Comment: @Bernard I already defined the formatting of numbered and unnumbered chapters with `titlesec`; this works pretty well. The problem is just that I don't manage to get the unnumbered chapters, which I generate with `chapter*{}`, into the header ...

Comment: @MarioS.E. unfortunately that doesn't work ... I don't know why, but it doesn't show the chapter in the header by using `\addchap*{}` ... neither `\addchap[]{...}` helps :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the extended interpretion of the optional section argument by setting the class option

```
headings=optiontoheadandtoc
```

Then simple use

```
\addchap[tocentry={}]{The concerning one ...}
```

to get

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  oneside,
  BCOR=5mm,
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=35mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=15mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{mparhack}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thechapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{0pt}{}{}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\tableofcontents

\addchap[tocentry={}]{The concerning one ...}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter[Chapter 1]{Chapter 1}
\blindtext[10]
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I got a warning because of the used package `titlesec` but the code works for me. Nevertheless you can also format the chapters without `titlesec`. Try

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\thechapter\autodot}}
%%% the following code needs version 3.17 or newer
  \renewcommand\sectionformat{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\thesection\autodot}}
  \renewcommand\subsectionformat{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}}
  \renewcommand\subsubsectionformat{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\thesubsubsection\autodot}}
%%% the following code works with 3.16 or older
  %\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{#3\autodot}}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thechapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{0pt}{}{}
```

Comment: `KOMA` classes complain 'recently' about `titlesec`, so it is a good idea to use the `KOMA` commands to rebuild the chapter headings. Nice solution!

Comment: Thank you for both solutions! ... - For the first one, I don't get a warning.
I used the `titlesec`-package 'cause my chapter/section-formats are a little bit complex. This was just an example - I added those I use in my 'main-question'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with  `titleps`. Redefining pagestyles with this package conflicts with `scrpage2`, so I deleted it, as I deleted the packages that weren't used in your code.

```
\documentclass[oneside,openright,paper=a4,BCOR=5mm,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=35mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=15mm, footskip=12mm, bindingoffset = 5mm}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thechapter}}{0pt}{#1}%
\titleformat{name = \chapter, numberless}[hang]{}{}{0pt}{\chaptermark{#1}#1}%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{0pt}{}{}

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\sethead[\slshape\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\slshape\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\clearscrheadfoot
%\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{The concerning one ...}
\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[7]
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[8-12]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[13-18]

\end{document}
```

[image]