# How do you include the title of \section*{...} for the header?

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I got a problem for my thesis. How does it work, that \section*{...} is used for the section title in the header?

For sections with a \section{...} my definition is working as wanted:

[image]

For sections with a \section*{...} it is not displaying a title at all, if no \section is defined before:

[image]

and the title of the last section, if there already was a \section:

[image]

Here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titelpage]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setheadsepline[text]{.4pt}[\color{black}]
\lehead*{\headmark}
\lohead*{\headmark}

\begin{document}
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstrakt} %Add it to the ToC
    \section*{Abstrakt} %Using * so its not considert for numberd section-structure 
    some text
\end{document}
```

What do I have to add? Is it possible to set a title manually?

Comment: Which is the documentclass of your real-life document? Is it `article` (as per your MWE) or one of the `KOMA-script` classes, such as `scrbook` or `scrartcl` (as per your tag)? Asking because the KOMA classes offer easy solutions for your request.

Comment: For the KOMA classes, see the second part of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368548/) which answers practically the same question; also see [this slightly different solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183002/)

Comment: I use the article class. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Well `scrlayer-scrpage` is in fact a part of KOMA-script, so you do have a point :) I was just thrown off by your mention of a "thesis" as opposed to an article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\markboth{Abstrakt}{Abstrakt}` to the `section*` title.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,titelpage]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setheadsepline[text]{.4pt}[\color{black}]
\lehead*{\headmark}
\lohead*{\headmark}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY for the dummy text <<<

\begin{document}
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstrakt} %Add it to the ToC
    \section*{Abstrakt \markboth{Abstrakt}{Abstrakt}} %Using * so its not considert for numberd section-structure 
    \kant[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked completely fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: @TrizZm4ster Thank you for your feedback!